# How to summarize column value by multiple non-excluding dummy columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarize (min, max, mean, sd) my distance value by group, which are non-exclusive and are denoted by a dummy column. Converting to a long format would be a solution but this does not work when groups are non-exclusive.

My data looks like this:

| distance | group1 | group2 | group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 25 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 33 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 92 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we can use `pivot_longer()` even with non-exclusive groups. Below `distance` `51` is included in `group1` and  `group2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("group"),
               names_to = "group") %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(across(distance, list(min = min,
                                  max = max,
                                  mean = mean,
                                  sd = sd)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   group  distance_min distance_max distance_mean distance_sd
#>   <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 group1           25           51            38        18.4
#> 2 group2           51           51            51        NA  
#> 3 group3           92           92            92        NA
```

As @moodymudskipper points out in the comments, we can use `.by` since dplyr v. >= 1.1.0 and the tibble package (attached with tidyverse) also offers  `lst` as replacement for `list` which automatically names the list elements after their input objects:

```r
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("group"),
               names_to = "group") %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  summarise(across(distance,
                   lst(min, max, mean, sd)
                   ),
            .by = group)
```

Data from OP

```r
dat <- tribble(
  ~distance,    ~group1,    ~group2,    ~group3,
  51,   1,  1,  0,
  25,   1,  0,  0,
  33,   0,  0,  0,
  92,   0,  0,  1
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I like the `tibble::lst()` function to do `lst(min, max, mean, sd)` instead of naming explicitly, it's attached with the tidyverse.

Comment: And we now have the `.by` arg that might make it yet a little sweeter

Comment: @moodymudskipper: Thanks for pointing this out. I forgot about `lst()` and I also added the `.by` argument as another option!

Answer (score 4):

If you want a horizontal output the following might fit

```r
library(dplyr, w = F)

summarize(data, across(starts_with("group"), list(
  min = ~min(distance[. == 1]), 
  max = ~max(distance[. == 1]), 
  mean = ~mean(distance[. == 1]), 
  sd = ~sd(distance[. == 1])
)))
#>   group1_min group1_max group1_mean group1_sd group2_min group2_max group2_mean
#> 1         25         51          38  18.38478         51         51          51
#>   group2_sd group3_min group3_max group3_mean group3_sd
#> 1        NA         92         92          92        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice pure-dplyr solution! If someone want to stack the output, just add `%>% tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("group", ".value"), names_sep = "_")`

Answer (score 2):

A base R answer:

```r
mySummary <- function(x) c(summary(x), SD = round(sd(x), 2))
sapply(dat[-1], \(x) mySummary(dat$distance[x == 1]))

        group1 group2 group3
Min.     25.00     51     92
1st Qu.  31.50     51     92
Median   38.00     51     92
Mean     38.00     51     92
3rd Qu.  44.50     51     92
Max.     51.00     51     92
SD       18.38     NA     NA
```

Comment: Really nice and short base R approach!  However, I think the `sd` is missing.

Comment: careful though, the output is a matrix

Comment: @TimTeaFan one can add additional measures with `c`

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = "distance", variable.name = "group")[
  value == 1,
  lapply(
    c(min = min, max = max, mean = mean, sd = sd),
    function(f) do.call(f, list(distance))
  ),
  group
]
```

gives

```
    group min max mean       sd
1: group1  25  51   38 18.38478
2: group2  51  51   51       NA
3: group3  92  92   92       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `reframe` + `map_dfr()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  reframe(map_dfr(pick(starts_with("group")),
                  ~ filter(pick(distance), .x == 1) %>%
                    summarise(across(distance, lst(min, max, mean, sd))),
                  .id = "group"))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  group  distance_min distance_max distance_mean distance_sd
  <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1 group1           25           51            38        18.4
2 group2           51           51            51        NA
3 group3           92           92            92        NA
```